# Nginx ignore loaded config and search in "/etc/nginx/html/index.html"

Tags: nginx

I update nginx to 1.16 and my website stop to work.
It look for file in "/etc/nginx/html/index.html"

Here is the log

```
2019/05/10 18:16:24 [error] 125559#125559: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 37.117.29.208, server: next.dday.it, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "next.dday.it"
2019/05/10 18:16:25 [error] 125559#125559: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 37.117.29.208, server: next.dday.it, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "next.dday.it"
2019/05/10 18:21:14 [error] 125700#125700: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 37.117.29.208, server: next.dday.it, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "next.dday.it"
```

This is my nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

        # SSL Settings
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";
        ssl_ecdh_curve prime256v1:secp384r1;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY; # change to SAMEORIGIN for iframes
# Optimize session cache
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;

        # Enable session tickets
        ssl_session_tickets on;

        # OCSP Stapling
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 valid=60s;
        resolver_timeout 2s;

        ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 32 16k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_min_length 250;
        gzip_types image/jpeg image/bmp image/svg+xml text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/x-icon;

        # Brotli Settings
brotli on;
        brotli_comp_level 4;
        brotli_buffers 32 8k;
        brotli_min_length 100;
        brotli_static on;
    brotli_types image/jpeg image/bmp image/svg+xml text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/x-icon;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.*;
```

And If I try with NGINX -T my config under sites-enabled is loaded!

```
upstream puma_next.dday.it {
  server unix:/home/scriptamanent/apps/dday.it/shared/tmp/sockets/dday.it-puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name next.dday.it;
  return 301 https://next.dday.it$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name next.dday.it;
}


server {
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/next.dday.it/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/next.dday.it/privkey.pem;
  root /home/scriptamanent/apps/dday.it/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma_next.dday.it;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
  error_page 503 @503;

  location @puma_next.dday.it {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
ssi on;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_pass http://puma_next.dday.it;
    # limit_req zone=one;
    access_log /home/scriptamanent/apps/dday.it/shared/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/scriptamanent/apps/dday.it/shared/log/nginx.error.log;
  }

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location ^~ /packs/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
  }

  location = /50x.html {
    root html;
  }

  location @503 {
    error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
    }
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
  }

  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
    return 405;
  }

  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
 }
}
```

And this is my configuration in sites-enabled.
As I told you if I try Nginx -T the config is loaded.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a complete `server` block for `next.dday.it` which serves nothing but static files:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; 
    server_name next.dday.it;
}
```

It has no document `root`, so the default is used: `/etc/nginx/html`.

My guess is that you should instead have the `server_name` in the *next* `server` block, which doesn't have one, but which does have the SSL certificate configured for `next.dday.it`.

I would move the `server_name` to that next `server` block, and then delete the remains of this one.